# In PHP, what is exactly a curl handle?

Tags: php, session, curl

I've been looking for the answer but I could not get a clear explanation.

Is it an object? What attributes or methods does it have?

**EDIT 1**
So a handle is of the resource type and the resource type in PHP means some sort of external resource.

What then does this resource have under the hood ?

Comment: And did you read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)  ?

Comment: A handle is a PHP variable of the "resource" type. Behind the scenes that's a pointer to some C structure. In that case a curl status/parameter struct. -- Please narrow your question down to one question. Or explain the usage or behaviour relevancy, or what specific code you need to know this for.

Comment: @adeneo Ah yes, I am still looking at it. Perhaps I completely missed a paragraph where it says what a curl handle is in the documentation. Do you know which bit of the documentation says what they are ? Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under the hood a `resource` is a `C` pointer variable, that keeps alive unless you are explicitly closing it. Examples are open files, database connections or like in your case a curl handle.

If you dig more into `C` (PHP is written is C) you'll find that kind of handles very often.

---

To get the type of any object in PHP you can issue:

```
$type = gettype($variable);
```

If `$type` equals `object` you can get the class name using `get_class()`:

```
if($type === 'object') {
    $type = get_class($variable);
}
```

---

If you try that with a curl handle, you will see it is a `resource`:

```
$curl = curl_init();
var_dump(gettype($curl)); // string(8) "resource"
```

Btw, on top of the documentation page of every PHP function you'll find the signature of that function, for `curl_init()` it looks like this:

```
resource curl_init ([ string $url = NULL ] )
```

You see, the return type is a `resource`. But however because of the loose typing system of PHP methods are allowed to return various return types. Especially in case of error most PHP methods will return `false`. Check the section `Return Values` for every method you'll use in PHP.

Comment: It seems odd to me that php.net search results show nothing for the keyword "handle". Also the curl_init() document does not have a link to the "resource" type.

Comment: Nobody is perfect and nobody pays that guys. You are free to add the link while joining the PHP doc team. Google `PHP type resource`. Also I think the PHP manual is - compared to other languages -  great!

Comment: Ah yes. I actually tried to edit and add a simple link to the page that explains what the resource type is.

Answer (score 1):

From PHP-8 `CurlHandle` [has become](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlhandle.php) `object`, instead of `resource`. To get some properties/manipulations onto that object, you need to use [curl-functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php).